# How do I develop an application with a Layered Architecture using Agile methodologies?

Tags: agile, scrum, agile-project-management

In Domain Driven Design applied architectures, you should start developing domain model and test it. After a model occurred, then you can use the model objects in other layers like that Presentation Layer or Persistence Layer.

My question is how to separated tasks to team members like this Project?

1. Before a model created, frontend developers can not do anything.Because objects are not ready.
2. Does Domain Model created by multiple developers like this projects? For example ProductService and OrderService are developing and testing by two different developers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agile methodologies usually recommend approaching each feature in [Vertical Slices](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2011/11/21/understanding-the-vertical-slice/) (also see [here](http://dhondtsayitsagile.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/the-keystone-habit-thin-vertical-slices.html)).

This means that you should develop a feature from end-to-end.

When doing this you should apply ["You aren't gonna need it" or YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). This means that you should build "just enough" of each layer to implement your feature.

You probably don't need the full domain model implementing for each feature. You backend coders implement the parts that the frontend coders need, just before they need it.

[image: Vertical Slices]

Comment: Do you mean that frontend developers waits until domain model occured?

Comment: They wait until the smallest amount of the domain model is completed. Possibly implementing it themselves.